# ListView перекрывает FloatingActionBar

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-layout, material-design, design

Когда ListView перестает влазить в экран, он перекрывает fab, после чего кликнуть по fab уже не получается (пока ListView не "дошел" до fab - fab кликабелен). Все клики идут на элементы списка. На скрине видно, как разделители идут поверх fab.

[image: Вид в эмуляторе]

Gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

XML

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="torin.dmitry.todolist.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@color/colorToolbar"
        android:elevation="@dimen/normalMargin"
        />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/main_fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_cancel"
            app:elevation="4dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            />

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Фрейм используется для фрагментов

```
@Override
public void setFragment(Fragment f) {
    getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.main_frame, f)
            .commit();
```

Проблема **только на эмуляторе** (Genymotion, на нативном попробовать не могу). Эмулируется Nexus S API 16 480 x 800.

Физическое устр-во на котором все работает: Xiaomi API 21 1080 x 1920

Comment: А listView где находится? или вы его програмно на main_frame кладете?

Comment: @АндроидАндроид программно на main_frame

Comment: Это правильное поведение, так как он кладется поверх вашего fab. Если нет необходимости в програмном создании listview, то просто добавьте его в разметку в ваш frameLayout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, есть такая проблема до API 21.

Суть её в том, что по факту, в вашей разметке FAB находится в контейнере на 0 уровне и все последующие добавляемые элементы перекрывают его (т.к. отрисовка детей в контейнере происходит по порядку их добавления, то самые последние имеют максимальный z-индекс) и, соответственно, клики не проходят. При этом с API 21 FAB всегда выше любой вьюхи в одном с ним контейнере.

У вас 3 варианта:

1. Установить программно z-индекс для FAB:

```
ViewCompat.setZ(fab, 42);
```

2. Переделать разметку так, чтобы FAB был всегда выше в иерархии чем фрагменты. Например сделав ещё один FrameLayout внутри текущего и в него фрагменты добавлять.
3. Создать свой контейнер в котором реализовать свой порядок отрисовки детей. Пример тут: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39161932/3212712

Comment: Помог 2-ой пункт. Программно установить не получилось. Пробовал в onCreateView сразу после привязки fab прописывать ViewCompat.setZ(fab, 10-42-99) а так же при каждой смене фрагмента перед и/или после смены - не работает у меня